# Implement a stack with a efficient `has` operation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, stack

I need a data structure which has 3 operations: 1. `push`, 2. `pop` 3. `has`. It is like a stack with a set-like element lookup. The `has` operation should return true iff the stack contains the argument. I need the `has` operation to be fast, how do I implement it?

Examples:

1. push(1), push(2), push(1), pop(). // Expect has(1) to be true.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you could make an argument that, if you need a `has/contains` method, it probably shouldn't *be* a stack. However, if *I* needed such functionality (and it was an object-oriented language), I would simply inherit from an actual stack and then intercept the `push` and `pop` calls to also maintain another alternate collection (e.g., a sorted resizable vector, or a sorted list, or counting set, other suitable one).

Every time something was pushed, I'd add it to the alternate collection as well. Upon popping, it would also be removed from the alternate collection.

Then your `push` and `pop` operations become (hopefully only) marginally slower and, your `has` method uses the alternate collection which is presumably a lot faster than a basic stack would be (using the method of examining every element in the stack to see if the item is in there).

And yes, you may have duplicate data but optimisation is often a space/time trade-off. In any case, you could mostly avoid any real impact by using pointers in (references to) the stack items within the alternate collection.

---

Since you haven't specified a language, and Python is the ultimate pseudo-code anyway :-), here's how I would approach it in that language. First a basic stack class with nothing other than `push/pop`:

```py
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []                 # Empty list to start.

    def push(self, item):
        self.stack.append(item)         # Add to list end.

    def pop(self):
        item = self.stack[-1]           # Get list end,
        self.stack = self.stack[:-1]    #   shorten list by one,
        return item                     #   and return it.
```

The class that inherits from that calls the base class for each item but also maintains a dictionary (associative array) which maps item to a count (effectively a counting set).

```py
class AltStack(Stack):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()               # Defer to base but
        self.alternate = {}              # also create alternate.

    def push(self, item):
        super().push(item)               # Defer to base but
        try:                             # also increment in
            self.alternate[item] += 1    # alternate, creating if
        except KeyError:                 # not yet set.
            self.alternate[item] = 1

    def pop(self):
        item = super().pop()             # Defer to base. Then
        if self.alternate[item] == 1:    # decrement in alternate,
            del self.alternate[item]     # deleting item from
        else:                            # alternate when count
            self.alternate[item] -= 1    # reaches zero.
        return item

    def has(self, item):
        return item in self.alternate    # Use alternate for "has".
```

Then all you need is the simplest of test harnesses:

```py
my_stack = AltStack()

# Push 0, two each of 1-6, and 7.

for i in range(7):
    my_stack.push(i)
    my_stack.push(i+1)

# Pop each, displaying both it and whether stack has specific item.

for i in range(14):
    print("Popping", my_stack.pop(), "has(4)? =", my_stack.has(4))
```

As you can see from the (annotated) output, this works as expected:

```py
Popping 7 has(4)? = True  <-- 4 was pushed twice, has(4) true.
Popping 6 has(4)? = True
Popping 6 has(4)? = True
Popping 5 has(4)? = True
Popping 5 has(4)? = True
Popping 4 has(4)? = True  <-- first 4 popped, has(4) still true.
Popping 4 has(4)? = False <-- final 4 popped, has(4) now false.
Popping 3 has(4)? = False
Popping 3 has(4)? = False
Popping 2 has(4)? = False
Popping 2 has(4)? = False
Popping 1 has(4)? = False
Popping 1 has(4)? = False
Popping 0 has(4)? = False <-- and stay false forever.
```

Keep in mind this is an *example* showing how it could be done as a concept. I make no judgement call on whether dictionaries are more efficient than list though I suspect they are for medium to large structures. So try to remember this concept nature before you start to raise issues with the way I've done things.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is good enough with `push`, `pop`, `has` all having average time complexity of O(1), with an extra O(n) spaces used. The counting trick is nice.

Answer (score -1):

Why not it is possible to extend the stack data structure class in java and add functionality so as to implement your specified has/contains method as required.
If you wish this idea works out I can write the necessary code for it.